# How to trigger MouseOver event over Path?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I want to have an image button with highlighting on `MouseOver`. In the `MainWindow` I have a canvas (icon) placed inside a rectangle.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="ejectRectangle" Width="35" Height="35" Margin="0,0,0,20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ejectImageButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
```

In App.xaml, I attached a trigger to the Canvas.Path in order to obtain a highlighting effect (the highlighting color is Red in this case):

```
<Canvas x:Key="ejectImageButton" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="appbar_control_eject" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
            <Path Width="38" Height="30.0833" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="22.1667" Stretch="Fill" Data="F1 M 19,44.3333L 57,44.3333L 57,52.25L 19,52.25L 19,44.3333 Z M 38,22.1667L 57,41.1667L 19,41.1667L 38,22.1667 Z ">
                <Path.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, Path=theme, Converter={StaticResource idealForegroundConverter}}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Path.Style>     
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
```

The converter is used just to set a darker or lighter color, depending on the app theme (I'm using MahApps). The problem is that **the `MouseOver` event never triggers. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?". You've put the Canvas with the Path in a VisualBrush. Brushes don't receive any input events like e.g. `MouseEnter`. The `IsMouseOver` property of the Path is never set.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks! But how can I display the canvas in the MainWindow?

Comment: Use the ContentControl directly instead of a Rectangle?

Comment: @Clemens Thank you! I can use the icon now with highlighting.

Comment: @Clemens It seems that placing it inside a ContentControl does not allow resizing the icon, whereas this was possible using a Rectangle. Can resizing be done with ContentControl?

Comment: @Clemens I mention that the ContentControl has HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch".

Comment: There is a Path with fixed size in a Canvas. Not much chance for resizing by layout. You could try to put the whole thing in a Viewbox.

Comment: @Clemens It works with a Viewbox, but sadly, I do not have control over the icon size. I have to adjust it by hand.